70s-80s sci-fi movie featuring Zed, resembling a young Sean Connery with a ponytail and a mustache, dressed in bikini-like shorts and thigh-high boots
I was in a hotel last night that only had cable, so I could not see what the title of this movie was. There was a guy named Zed who looked like a young Sean Connery with dark hair, a ponytail, and a mustache. He was dressed in bikini-like shorts and thigh-high boots.
From the short amount that I saw of this, it looked like a B sci-fi movie from the mid-seventies. There were other "creatures" dressed similar to this Zed character, but they had white masks on. The movie was in English. It looked like it was possibly post-apocalyptic.

It was Sean Connery. It's Zardoz from 1974.

In the distant future Earth is divided into two camps, the barely civilized group and the overly civilized one with mental powers. A plague is attacking the second group, after which its members cease to have any interest in life and become nearly catatonic. When Zed, one of the barbarians, crosses over, the tenuous balance in their world is threatened. 

Here's the trailer (Warning: Contains Oddity):




Are you kidding me right now??? THAT was Sean Connery??  I just thought it was some nobody that looked like him, or I just would have checked SC's imdb...too funny!!! Thanks for your quick answer.

Oddity? This all seems perfectly mundane to me.
